# Javascript code to apache velocity

Tags: javascript, html, velocity

I'm a beginner at velocity but I really want to learn.
I did a page with various products like in an e-commerce site.

I wanted to add the selected products via check boxes to an array and did this javascript code.

```
var test = [];

$(":checkbox").change(function(){
  if((this).checked){
    test.push(this.id);
  }
  else{
    test.splice(test.indexOf(this.id), 1);
  }    
});
```

now I want to try to convert this code so that it can be used in velocity. So far I can only set the array in velocity like this:

```
#set ($test = [] )
```

and I have a vague idea that you can add items to the array in velocity like this:

```
#set ( $sample = $test.add("sample") )
```

but I have no idea how to do the checkbox thing

is there a way to do this in velocity? or at least a way to use this code.

Answer (score 1):

You can't transfer the JavaScript code to Velocity completely. At least not if you expect the same behavior of your page.

That's because your Velocity template is rendered server sided and you'll get nothing but HTML (including scripts of course). Meaning, when you see your page there is no Velocity functionality left that could react on your click on the checkbox.

So, if you want to stick to Velocity you can evaluate the checkbox in a further request after submitting the page with common methods and change whatever backing object there is.

If you need this page to react immediately on a click, this has to done client sided, hence you must leave the JavaScript code in the page. Here you can decide whether to let JavaScript do all the work or to make an asynchronous request and reload just parts of the page.

Comment: I see... I found this though... wont this be applicable somehow? http://wiki.apache.org/velocity/VelocityViewMacros

Comment: or is there any other way to push the selected elements into a velocity declared array because I need to display those selected items into another page...

Comment: The description of that macro reads 'Checkbox control. "Remembers" checkbox choices made by user on previous form submission'. That's exactly what I meant: There has to be a submission (or request) first from which you read the data. This macro expects some input. Filling the objects that represent this input is left to you.

Comment: There is for sure a way to get what you want, but it's kind of hard to advise how, because one would need more information about your project. I think you should look for example code first and fiddle about a little to get acquainted to how Velocity works in general. Cheers.

Comment: ok I will study more about it. One last question though, what if I append the id to the url via js? is it possible to get the id from the url through velocity?

Comment: Please don't take what I write as an offense, because it's really not meant to be that way: You asking the wrong questions, because you seem to have a wrong idea about Velocity and it's place in the request-response-cycle. Take your time and read basic examples. Your ideas prove creativity, but you're kind of putting the cart before the horse.